# How to fix an Error: Cannot find any entity corresponding to?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-api

I'm writing a Checker in Python. I have a list of numbers in input_numbers.txt file, which I need to check one by one for Telegram registration.

After running the code, the following error pops up (I replaced the phone numbers with +XXXXXXXXXXXXX):

> +XXXXXXXXXXX is registered
>
> Error: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "+XXXXXXXXXXX"
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

The first number in the list is registered, the script successfully enters it into the correct file registered_numbers.txt

Starting with the second number, whether it is registered or not, this error appears.

Here is the code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PhoneNumberInvalidError

api_id = 12345678
api_hash = '1234567890qwertyuiop'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

input_file_path = 'input_numbers.txt'
registered_numbers_file_path = 'registered_numbers.txt'
non_registered_numbers_file_path = 'non_registered_numbers.txt'

async def check_phone_numbers():
    try:
        await client.connect()
        if not await client.is_user_authorized():
            await client.send_code_request('+XXXXXXXXXX')
            code = input('Enter the code: ')
            await client.sign_in('+XXXXXXXXXX', code)

        with open(input_file_path, 'r') as input_file, \
             open(registered_numbers_file_path, 'w') as registered_numbers_file, \
             open(non_registered_numbers_file_path, 'w') as non_registered_numbers_file:
            for line in input_file:
                phone_number = line.strip()
                try:
                    await client.get_entity(phone_number)
                    print(f'{phone_number} is registered')
                    registered_numbers_file.write(f'{phone_number}\n')
                except PhoneNumberInvalidError:
                    print(f'{phone_number} is not registered')
                    non_registered_numbers_file.write(f'{phone_number}\n')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')
    finally:
        await client.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.loop.run_until_complete(check_phone_numbers())
```

I think we need to change the method.

If remove the try-catch:

> +XXXXXXXXXXXX is registered Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\ProjectsNOW\PyTelega\telegram checker without try-catch —
> копия.py", line 35, in 
> client.loop.run_until_complete(check_phone_numbers())   File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 587, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "D:\ProjectsNOW\PyTelega\telegram checker without try-catch — копия.py", line 25, in check_phone_numbers
> await client.get_entity(phone_number)   File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py",
> line 335, in get_entity
> result.append(await self._get_entity_from_string(x))   File "C:\Users\Nik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py",
> line 575, in _get_entity_from_string
> 'Cannot find any entity corresponding to "{}"'.format(string) ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "+XXXXXXXXXXXX"
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please remove the try-catch, and post in which line the error appears.

Comment: @shivarama23 I remove the try-catch, I added the result to the post

Comment: It looks like the phone number is not registered hence not fetching from the available dictionary/key value pairs.
Add "ValueError" in your exception handling as you are already handling the "PhoneNumberInvalidError" error.

Comment: @shivarama23 I added  "ValueError" in your exception handling as you wrote. Now appears after the first checked number on all the others this error +XXXXXXXXXX has an invalid format: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "+XXXXXXXXXXX". But all the numbers are in the correct format.